# Understanding RANSAC optimization

Tags: algorithm, math, ransac

I have read wikipedia's article and watched a few videos on RANSAC.

If I understand correctly, one of the many ways to optimize RANSAC are as follows:

1. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus), its the number of max iterations:

[image]

2. According to this [website](http://ros-developer.com/2018/01/07/ransac-algorithm-parameter-explained/), in the example of finding a line that fits the data, instead of checking my model against all the data samples, I can use the following formula and find the minimum number of samples that would allow me to determine if the 2 chosen points are good.

[image],

where 
N = number of samples

e = probability that a point is an outlier

s = number of points in a sample

p = desired probability that we get a good sample

I am mostly interested in the second optimization as I couldn't find as much information about it. Is this correct? What is the name of it?

Answer (score 0):

The first and the second representations are the same.
[image]